# IntelliJ IDEA - How to remove auto generated hints?

Tags: intellij-idea

Am trying out IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3 (being an Eclipse user, there's been a lot of great nods to both Jetbrains and IntelliJ IDEA being sophisticated, so I have been fooling around with it all day and actually enjoying some features).

Wrote a simple unit test (which worked) but am noticing inside the editor that its auto-inserting my variable's value with a grey background following a colon ":" afterwards and also inside the assertEquals() method its adding a grey background for the word "expected:".

After placing my mouse cursor and clicking the second button, a dialog came up stating "Disable Hints" and I was able to get rid of them manually, but am wondering how to not have them appear by default.

Attached is a screenshot (a picture speaks a thousand words)! :)

How can I turn this off? Am using the macOS version of IntelliJ IDEA.

[image: WeirdLabels.png]

Comment: CrazyCoder, after comparing both questions and answers, you are correct it is a duplicate. Can you delete this post?

Answer (score 0):

You can permanently disable them by go to **Preferences.. > Editor > General > Appearance > Show parameter name hints (uncheck to disable)**

Comment: Thank you Zico but unfortunately it was unchecked. :(